# Add efficiently 1 month to current date in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

What is the best way to add an expiry date in CakePHP?

I've got an "expiry date" column in my database, I want to add 1 month to the current date, and store this.  At the moment, I'm just using strings and plain PHP date functions to create a new date string to save:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +31 days");
$this->data['Access']['expires'] = $date;
```

Is there a "more CakePHP" way or efficient/performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise we're most probably talking about micro optimizations at best, so that probably shouldn't be your main concern. However, all the back and forth that you're doing there doesn't make much sense, a single call to `strtotime()` is all you need, ie

```
$this->data['Access']['expires'] = strtotime('+31 days');
```

This will result in a timestamp of "now + 31 days".

The Cake-ish way would be to use the `CakeTime` class, for example `CakeTime::fromString()`, like

```
App::uses('CakeTime', 'Utility');

$this->data['Access']['expires'] = CakeTime::fromString('+31 days');
```

When passing a string (it also accepts integers and `\DateTime` instances), this is basically just a wrapper for `strtotime()`, and an additional mechanism that incorporates the timezone set for your application, so while this will be a little bit slower of course, it might still be wise to use it.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Utilities > CakeTime](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime)**

Answer (score 0):

Better that adding 31 days is better to use 1 months this will add 30 or 31 days depending on which month will be the current date

$dateAfterOneMonth = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', CakeTime::fromString('+1 months'))

[image: PrintScreenShoot of Evaluate console in phpstorm]